# Getting error Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE in R

Tags: r

Here is my sample data

```
head( seismic_raw, n = 10)
    date mo day hr mn  sec     lat  long depth  mw
1   2000  1   1  1 19 28.3 41.950N 20.63     5 4.8
2   2000  1   1  4  2 28.4 35.540N 22.76    22 3.7
3   2000  1   2 10 44 10.9 35.850N 27.61     3 3.7
```

I'm getting an error when running:

```
seismic <- count(seismic_raw,c('date', 'mo'))
```

> Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: From which package comes function `count`?

Comment: @Pascal I believe it is from `plyr` package.

Comment: @JatinSaini Can you add a `dput` of your seismic_raw object? or at least an `str(seismic_raw)`

Comment: @Pascal:yes. It is from plyr package.

Comment: @agstudy : > str(seismic_raw)
'data.frame': 3823 obs. of  10 variables:
 $  date: int  2000 2000  ...
 $ mo   : int  1 1 ...
 $ day  : int  1 11 12 ...
 $ hr   : int  1 4 10  ...
 $ mn   : int  19 2 44  ...
 $ sec  : num  28.3 28.4  ...
 $ lat  : Factor w/ 735389 517 623 617 493 224 ...
 $ long : num  20.6 22.8 ..
 $ depth: num  5 22 3 32 ...
 $ mw   : num  4.8 3.7  ...