# Plotting Gaussian over histogram with ggplot2 and getting "Error length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE"

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I am trying to overlay a Gaussian on a histogram using R + ggplot2. This is a plot I have done many times before, but now I am getting an error that reads: "Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE."

My MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(1000, 100,10)) # Sample data

p <- ggplot(df, aes(df$x, fill = ..density..))+
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 20)+
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(df$x), sd = sd(df$x)))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(aspect.ratio = 1,
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')
p
```

Again, this is something I have done many times before. Perhaps it is because I have switched from my work computer to my home computer? I tried updating all of my packages, but this didn't seem to work. I am using RStudio Version 1.1.456, and the output of `version` is:

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.4                         
year           2018                        
month          03                          
day            15                          
svn rev        74408                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
nickname       Someone to Lean On
```

I have tried to find answers from the previous posts [Getting error Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437134/getting-error-error-lengthrows-1-is-not-true-in-r) and [dplyr Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376377/dplyr-error-lengthrows-1-is-not-true-in-r), with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take the `fill = density` out of the first call to `aes`. And don't use `$` in the `aes` - not the problem here, but often is.

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you so much! Do you mind explaining why it is bad practice to put `$` in the `aes`? Again, thank you. It worked perfectly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio - but apparently this was recently fixed in ggplot. Still, the $ is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! Always good to learn better practices to avoid breaking things in the future. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `fill` before assigning a value to y in aestethics. 
This works this way

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., fill = ..density..), bins = 20)+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(df$x), sd = sd(df$x)))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1,
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')
p
```

[image]